# Android: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android app to store personal info in SQLite database, withdraw them out and display the list in Activity.Actually,the moment users have put data into database and returned to Activity,the page must be refreshed to upgrade the list with something new data.I used the statement`onCreate(null)` to make it,but an exception came into being:`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached`.

Here is the code :

```
/* MainActivity */
public class MainActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity
        implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode==0x1&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                onCreate(null); // Upgrade the list
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button addItem=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addItem);
        addItem.setOnClickListener(this);
        .....
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.addItem:
                Intent intent=new Intent(this,AddItemActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0x1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

/*AddItemActivity*/
public class AddItemActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity
        implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);
        Button submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);//get submit button
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.submit:
                EditText editName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName),
                         editAge=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editAge);
                         insert(new Person(
                                        editName.getText().toString(),
                                        Integer.parseInt(editAge.getText().toString())));
                //return 
                setResult(RESULT_OK,null);
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

stackTrace is this:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.sqlitetest/com.example.sqlitetest.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController(FragmentManager.java:2871)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.attachHost(FragmentController.java:104)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:317)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85)
at com.example.sqlitetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
at com.example.sqlitetest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:23)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6915)
```

Comment: JSONReader use notifyDataSetChanged(); if use in Activity use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); instead of onCreate(null);

Comment: you should never invoke `onCreate` nor any activity lifecycle methods yourself

Comment: Why the -1?  Question seems reasonable and the resulting answer is useful.